# Need to get Focus on Anchorepane components

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Please help me out, in my Javafx application.I need to switch focus of AnchorPane children as i ordered .

I need to specify the "Tab Indexing/Ordering concept" here. 
Keyboard navigation between the children(text fields etc) with tab key in configurable orderly manner.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us the code of screenshot. Also if the Anchorpane does not fit to your needs, use another layout component.

Comment: @UlukBiy hi my requirement with anchorpane .I need the tab navigation in the order of a1,a2,a3,a4 (textfields Id's).default tab navigation for  this will fallows as a2,a1,a4,a3 in tab order.

Comment: The following Q&As [JavaFx: Change focus traversal policy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238928/javafx-change-focus-traversal-policy) and [Focus Traversal Policy in TitledPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385708/focus-traversal-policy-in-titledpane) will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

On your fxml you Textfield order are a2 a1 a4 a3 so ... the tab order will be the same.
order your textfield on your fxml a1 a2 a3 a4 and the tab will be ok