# Equivalent of AWT/Swing transferFocus in JavaFX

Tags: java, focus, javafx-2

In JavaFX, from within node A, is it possible to transfer the focus to the next focusable node, node B?

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238928/javafx-change-focus-traversal-policy/15250149#15250149

Comment: Thanks Alexander, but if I understand the link, that is solving a node ordering problem.  In this case, node B already correctly follows node A as defined by the default focus traversal policy.  My question is from within the handler code of node A, can I signal a transfer to the next node.

Comment: I think, there are two ways: a) get engine, and call it; b) simulate sending "tab" key pressing on the node. As far as I know, there is no direct API for transfer on a next node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Node's method impl_traverse to set focus on next focusable Node:

```
A.impl_traverse(Direction.NEXT)
```

or in JavaFX 8:

```
new KeyboardShortcutsHandler().traverse(A, Direction.NEXT)
```