# javafx borderpane - how to change tab traversal order?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In javafx BorderPane the tab traversal order is defined by the order of the children.

The problem is I have some Stage inheritance with a BorderPane on the base class, and BorderPane.setBottom() is called first.

This screws the tab order, since the bottom child is the first item on the children list.

I want to make the tab traversal on the BorderPane to be:

- top
- left
- center
- right
- bottom

How could I archieve this?

This makes more sense than the set (setTop, setCenter, ...) order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [JavaFX: How to change the focus traversal policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238928/javafx-how-to-change-the-focus-traversal-policy)

Answer (score 1):

It seems it can't be done.

The solution was to add AnchorPanes inside the BorderPane areas and calling setTop, setCenter, ... in the desired tab traversal order.